# How do I make a function only cast when a previous function has finished its job?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use some functions to calculate and show the distance of only the markers within a certain distance from their position, but the function is being cast as soon as the page loads so it's using an incorrect value

Here is my function for generating markers from the database:

```
<?php while($stmt -> fetch()) { ?>
var longi = "<?php echo $gLongitude; ?>";
var lati = "<?php echo $gLatitude; ?>";
var title = "<?php echo $gTitle; ?>";
createMarker(lati, longi, title);
<?php } $stmt -> close(); $mysqli -> close();?>
```

Which then calls createMarker

```
function createMarker(lati, longi, title) {
    var latLongMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, longi);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLongMarker,
        map: map,
        title: title
    });
    arrMarker.push(marker);
    marker.setMap(null);
    setMarker(latLongMarker);
}
```

Which then calls setmarker

```
function setMarker(position) {
    console.log(arrMarker.value);
    for (var i = 0; i < arrMarker.length; i++) {
        var latLong = arrMarker[i].getPosition();
        distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latLong, position);
        if (distance < 4000) {
            addMarker(arrMarker[i].getPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it keeps getting called before the geolocation is set using:

```
function locateMe() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
            map.setZoom(15);
            setMarkerPosition(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
        }, function() {
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your code to run after you have the position you should put that code inside the getCurrentPosition callback.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    map.setZoom(15);
    setMarkerPosition(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

    createMarker() // <---
}, function() {
    handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
});
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to turn the "async" code into a regular function that returns when its done. The best you can do is making the part where you call the next function into a parameter.

```
function locateMe(callback){
    googleMapsStuff(function(position){
       //things...
       callback(value_you_would_have_returned)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so I have one more problem, I just moved the php while loop to after the geolocation success, but now its calling createMarker which calls addMarker in turn so its adding the same marker to the map about 20 times, I just want it to add the markers that are less than 500 away, not keep adding the same ones everytime the loop passes

Comment: @XCritics: You probably should do the loop in Javascript instead of in PHP. Using PHP for this is essentially "copy pasting" code.